# java: no suitable constructor found for RemoteWebDriver(java.net.URL,org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities) constructor

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I update my selenium 3.4.0 to 3.7.1 
I am getting following error

```
Error:(88, 18) java: no suitable constructor found for RemoteWebDriver(java.net.URL,org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities)
    constructor org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.RemoteWebDriver(org.openqa.selenium.remote.CommandExecutor,org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.net.URL cannot be converted to org.openqa.selenium.remote.CommandExecutor)
    constructor org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.RemoteWebDriver(java.net.URL,org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities cannot be converted to org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities)
```

Comment: Firefox 45 isn't expected to work with the newest versions of selenium (3.4.0) and geckodriver (0.16.0). Support for geckodriver 0.16 is best in Firefox 52.0.3 and onwards.

see:
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver#supported-firefoxen

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3884 more details.